# Blind is so much better that this site. But why?

Tags: discussion

Blind is so much better than this site. I'm sure some fans of this site will disagree but by any empirical measure Blind is just a better watercooler site.

I am curious if anyone has any considered opinions on *why* blind is just so, so much better though? Or what the workplace does that makes it worse?

My own thoughts on the matter are the blind tax, a far loser moderation (the latter leading to a far friendlier community, if at the cost of the dreaded f bomb). I think perhaps the flaw with this site is the "canonical answer" concept, and the idea that it's meant to be a workplace appropriate professional site. Ppl want a break from the workplace to bitch about it, not be moderated by randoms.

For the unaware, blind has become the de-facto water-cooler app for discussing workplace topics. It is (supposedly) totally anonymous. I'm not affiliated with Blind at all, and I wouldn't really say I'm a user of it much (maybe read a post there 3x a week?). But I can tell you that i prefer it to this site.

Comment: "Ppl want a break from the workplace to bitch about it" - you are partly correct. The Workplace isn't really a "bitch about it" site. I've never heard of this Blind site. But then I've never been part of the "lets bitch about work" crowd. Have fun there.

Comment: " but by any empirical measure Blind is just a better watercooler site." - what empirical measures? What does "better" mean to you? What does "watercooler site" mean to you?

Comment: Is this not spam?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere users, growth, engagement, revenue... It's a shame nobody here wants to talk about the reasons blind is growing and so much bigger than TWP, because i think it would be a really interesting conversation.

Comment: @Chenmunka i don't think it's spam, certainly wasn't the intention.

Comment: I realise that wasn't the intention.  It is just that a post advertising one of SE's competitors could be seen that way.

Comment: @Chenmunka - it's more "shill" than "spam", IMHO.

Comment: Perhaps the conversation should be "TeamBlind versus GlassDoor". Seems like a far more relevant comparison, IMHO.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere glassdoor is good for employee reviews, but less so for salaries (levels.fyi). but it is also a legitimate company, and blind is also a company with revenue. i'm not even sure why TWP is around from a monetary pov?

Comment: @bharal - TWP isn't a site by itself, it's a part of StackExchange. I can't say I care at all about how much or how little money they make - I don't get any of it. I'm just here to try and help people. How much are you getting by shilling for Blind? Perhaps the new "Pets" topic is the big money-maker for Blind (ugh)? I can say that I'm happy TWP doesn't display the ads that TeamBlind does.

Comment: I don't see why The Workplace Meta would be a good place to discuss the relative merits of two websites with different goals and approaches. I'm rather surprised the Mods don't consider it completely off-topic and relegate the shilling to the Chit-Chat forum where it belongs. (shrug)

Answer (score 10):

As you acknowledge "Blind" is a completely different site concept to SE, so the notion that it would be "better" at fulfilling that concept is hardly surprising.

The Workplace SE has never aimed at being a site for *"Ppl want a break from the workplace to bitch about it, not be moderated by randoms."* I'm not knocking such sites, indeed I think it's probably a good thing that such sites exist, but that's not what *this* site is.

This is not a zero-sum game: If you want to use Blind and not TWP - great! If you want to use TWP and not Blind - great! If you want to use *both* - great!

Comment: i'm not particularly knocking the workplace. but it is very very niche. tech ppl with particular problems who drifted here from stackoverflow, basically. i am curious if anyone at all has given thought on why blind is doing a better job at creating a community, growing and, well, i can see that me using "helping" people might be contentious here, but certainly as it grows the number of ppl it helps will naturally eclipse this site.

Answer (score 7):

Having browsed through it, it seems like it's more of a reddit style commenting/gossiping board for a very localized community (tech people of the coastal US parts).

We aim to present thoughtful answers that help the asker, not comment threads or commiseration.

We aim to answer questions for a wider audience than just FAANGs.

Having browsed 2 dozen questions there, I have yet to find one with an insightful answer. Feel free to post a link to a good example of the OP being helped, since I seem to have missed it.

If you are looking for water cooler gossip of the tech industry in coastal US cities, chatting and commiserating without any solution present, then maybe Blind is for you.

It definetely is better at it than this site, because we consciously aim to *not* allow comments and gossip. The whole goal of SE sites is to provide answers, not opinions.

Comment: this is not really right tho, is it? This is what the stereotypical view of an autist *thinks* is right, but of course the questions on this site in particular do not, and cannot, lend themselves to a "correct" answer. Curiously, after arguing for "right" you then claim you looked at 20 or so questions and didn't find any "insightful" answers. Very rarely do questions have the answer within them, but less trivially one can hardly claim that your methodology is meaningful.

Comment: @bharal If you want to compare the sites, post a link to the other site, with a question and an answer that is somewhat helpful. And I will lay the bar real low here, by defining "helpful" as vaguely on topic and having more than one paragraph of *any* information.

Comment: https://www.teamblind.com/post/Waymo-Comp-Negotiation-pXd2GKTM

Comment: https://www.teamblind.com/post/How-should-I-handle-my-situation-as-a-contractor-raKwM0Uk

Comment: this wasn't that hard? i think you are over-valuing the canonical answers here, there is some good stuff on blind. there is also, of course, nonsense. but there is nonsense everywhere, (including this site)

Comment: but im really not trying to get into a battle on "worthiness" of the answers, unless your actual argument is "worthy answers makes for a low-use site"?

Comment: My argument is that over here, we don't deal in opinions. We don't answer "What should I do" questions. If you like those and want to get them answered (or would like a poll of random internet people on the topic), Blind might indeed be the better fit for you. I highly doubt I will ever read something about German labor law on Blind though. Or French health insurance. Or UK GDPR concerns. The two sites have different target demographics. You can use one, both or none, but it would be pointless for one to become "more like the other".

Comment: all the examples you give, curiously, really fall under the purview of "get a lawyer". having them "canonically answered" on a site, any site, is actually quite misleading. this site only functions for opinion based answers, legal (and thus "provably correct") are well out of limits

Comment: No, they are not. Anything that is (or should be) easily answerable by a professional that is not a lawyer (for example HR, or many other professions include legal education, even apprentices get legal education about what their current and future legal framework is) is absolutely on topic.

Comment: if it isn't answered by a lawyer and backed by that legal opinion, then how can it be called "correct"?  Even an opinion by a lawyer is not consistent across different cultures. I don't think any of the answers in this site can be called "correct", even the very best exist only for a slim snapshot of time and location. "Over here" all answers are opinions, and then they are voted up "by the masses", but the masses are small in number and so hardly representative of what is culturally correct.

Comment: You seem to have problems with wording that you made up yourself. I never said anything about "correct". You are arguing with your own straw man. I cannot help with that.

Comment: "My argument is that over here, we don't deal in opinions", "like a poll of random internet people on the topic", you are implying that answers here are *more correct* and *demonstrably correct*. Or were you implying something else?

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard of Blind, but my guess is for the same reason an online game is more fun than TWP, and Facebook is more useful for sharing things with my family than TWP.

They're all social media but have different purposes and uses.

Realistically the whole SE vision and rules and all the rest is nothing without the people who choose to come here. Without them it's just some online outfit hosting a game.

Answer (score 0):

Today nine of the top ten "questions" in the "tech industry" forum on Blind are all about Israel and Gaza, condemning one or the other and with comments that do nothing except insult another poster. The tenth is a person saying they will never use YouTube again.

I can find a thousand sites that allow me to have pointless arguments with people about contentious issues.

Use Blind if you want a pointless argument with someone you don't know. Use The Workplace to find answers.